# Mass dependence of the Euclidean Klein-Gordon propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation, propagator

Consider the Euclidean propagator

\begin{equation}
\Delta_E (x_1-x_2)\equiv \int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{e^{ip\cdot(x_1-x_2)}}{p^2+m^2}.
\end{equation}

I am a bit confused as to whether the 4-momentum, $p$, in the propagator contains implicit mass dependence in this scenario.

e.g., suppose one took a derivative of the propagator with respect to mass.  Would this simply yield the following?

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial m} \Delta_E (x_1-x_2)&=-2m\int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{i p\cdot(x_1-x_2)}}{(p^2+m^2)^2} \\
&=-\frac{m}{4\pi}K_0 \left(m|x_1-x_2|\right),
\end{align}
where $K_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Or does the 4-momentum carry some mass dependence that would complicate this?

Comment: You can evaluate the integral before taking the derivative, leading to [this result](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280212/how-do-i-derive-the-greens-function-for-nabla2-m2-in-d-dimensions) with the substitution $d=4$.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake Good point.  Perhaps I will be able to use the result in your link and some Bessel function identities to show these are equivalent

Comment: How could $p$ have mass dependence?  All four of its degrees of freedom are being integrated over.