# Asymptotic form of a Coulomb-like integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, fourier-transform, integration, asymptotics

I need to evaluate or work out the asymptotic scaling of the following integral:

\begin{equation}
I~=~\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} dq d^2p  \frac{e^{i\vec{p}\cdot \vec{r}}e^{iq z}}{p^2 + \frac{1}{g^2}q^4}
\end{equation}

where $g$ is some parameter, $\vec{p} = (p_x,p_y)$, $r=(x,y)$ and we have explicitly distinguished the $z$-momenta: $q= p_z$. I am interested in the large distance limit. So if there is some cutoff scale $l$ then I want the asymptotic form when $r,z>>l$ and also when $z>>r>>l$.

It's a bit like the calculation to derive the Coulomb interaction between two-point sources in 3+1D Maxwell theory except here, in the 'propagator', the $z$-component of the momenta is $q^4$ rather than $q^2$. I have tried various tricks like the Schwinger method to no avail. I would be grateful for any guidance.

Comment: Closing the contour with an arc and using the residue theorem?

Comment: I was able to get an expression involving modified Bessel functions using Mathematica. I can outline how, or do you want to know how the special functions are derived?

Comment: @SethWhitsitt Thanks for this. I'd appreciate an outline. Presumably if I have the form in terms of Bessel functions I can find their large r asymptotics somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Identify $m=q^2/g$ with mass for a [Green's function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/280212/2451) in 2+0D:
$$I~=~\int_{\mathbb{R}}\! dq ~e^{iq z} K_0(q^2r/g).$$